# how to set an ip range for a virtualhost in host file

Tags: windows, apache, virtualhost, wampserver

I want to let another person on my LAN see my Virtual host. I took some steps and now he can see my localhost when he enters my IP as an URL in browser. he couldn't see my virtualhost (shop.test) yet. so I edited his host file. I added my IP(192.168.1.3) tab shop.test. now he is able to see my vhost too. but there is a problem. my IP is Dynamic and for some reasons it should be this way. how can I use a range IP for shop.test in host file? or is there any other way for the purpose? 
and what is the meaning of `::1 localhost` in host file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`::1 localhost` in your HOSTS file is the equivalent of `127.0.0.1 localhost` but for the IPV6 address range. It is the loopback address for IPV6 like 127.0.0.1 is.

Modern browser will likely as not attempt to use the IPV6 range by default is they can

The PC running WAMPServer should be configured to use a static IP Address. Obviously it should not move or as you see it makes it difficult for other users to find it.

See [this site for instructions on how to configure your PC with a static IP Address](https://portforward.com/networking/static-ip-windows-10.htm)